# How to migrate KVM based VMs running in LVM setup to Vmdk images

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, migration

I am using KVM on Ubuntu Server 10.04. and Virtual Machines are running on it in LVM.
I have to migrate some of them to Vmware server.How can I achieve this?
I searched and came across some links but they all talked converting vmdk images to qcow or so.In this case I have OS in LVM.

I also looked at man page of qemu-img and as I understand it should do what I am asking in this thread. But how exactly should I proceed in this case.Since it is not a file based image (OS running in an LVM which has filesystem in that LVM).
So I am not able to understand what should I be doing to achieve the same.
Can I achieve the above with snapshots of LVMs rather than shutting down the VM itself.

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create an LVM snapshot volume and convert it with `qemu-img`:

```
lvcreate -L592M -s -n myvolume /dev/myvg/myvolume_snapshot
qemu-img convert /dev/myvg/myvolume_snapshot -O vmdk myvolume.vmdk
```

Comment: Ok this is great.I will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Converter doesn't clearly support KVM images, but you could treat your KVM image like a physical machine and use VMware Converter as you would a P2V conversion.

Comment: I tried that but it failed to detect the Virtual Machine.

Comment: Did you run it from the original guest or from another machine?

Comment: I tried it from another machine on the original machine installation itself had failed.

Answer (score -1):

```
qemu-img convert win2k3.img -O vmdk win2k3.vmdk
```

try out above command :)

Comment: Its not a .img file it is on LVM.